# Why is my submit button outside its container?

Tags: html, css

As you can see on the picture below, my submit button ("envoyer" in french) is placed outside its container (the container has a red background and is called .footer-content)
I haven't been able to recreate the issue on jsfiddle so here is the direct link (I haven't been able to identify the issue using firebug)

```
.footer-content {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: auto;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 9;
  max-width: 700px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please share the html and css code. Try increasing the height of the container.

Comment: There is an extra </div> at the end of your code. This may cause trouble.

Comment: Thanks. How did you catch the extra DIV? (I always have difficulties to catch thing lie this).

Comment: Please also post the relevant HTML markup in the question so it remains useful after you remove your test page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your formulars position is absolute and its containers height is auto (absolute positioned elements don´t influence their parents height)

Use this CSS for your formular

```
#contactfrm {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.footer-content {
    margin: 40px auto auto auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    height: auto;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 9;
    overflow: auto;
}
```